# XLIFF source with HTML content

Tags: translate, xliff

Is it common to give to a translator a XLIFF which contains HTML?

Do CAT tools support HTML tags properly?

```
<trans-unit id="1" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>This is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;</source>
</trans-unit>
```

Update:

I'm working on an HTML5 WYSIWYG editor with widgets, and we need to have an export for translation feature.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [XLIFF 1.2 Presentation Guide for HTML](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/xliff-profile-html/xliff-profile-html-1.2-cd02.html).

Ideally you need to encapsulate the HTML elements in XLIFF elements like this:
`<g id='d' ctype='bold'>bold</g>`.

Most CAT tools support all the native XLIFF elements but will treat escaped HTML as plain text, which is likely to cause issues.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that link. Don't usually CAT tools have settings which make them understand the HTML tags within the `<source>` such that it's not required to have the `<source>` with XLIFF `<g>` tags?

Comment: I'm thinking about popular tools like MemQ or Trados. I'm trying to see if there's a way without having to do the transformation to XLIFF tags. These tools can do this if the input file is HTML, so I'm thinking they should be able to somehow handle embedded HTML in the XLIFF

Comment: Trados Studio will treat the escaped HTML as plain text and memoQ will do slightly better using a cascading filter (XLIFF + regex) but this requires parsing the HTML using regex and we all know how that ends.

Comment: Thanks again. Creating the XLIFF `<g>` tags looks cumbersome to me. I wonder how people usually do this? How do they create XLIFF files based on the HTML? Funny thing is many CAT tools already accept importing HTML files, and each display the HTML tags with specific colored marks.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a HTML file that needs to be translated it is not common to convert it to XLIFF because most translation environments support HTML. If you have some other format (for example Java .properties, or .resx or .json with embedded HTML content) you should check with your translator if his environment handles your format. Generally speaking, every conversion between file types may break some characters that have a special meaning in the native file format, like < and > in XML and HTML, apostrophes in .properties files, commas and double quotes in csv files, and so on. Avoid unnecessary conversions if possible.

Since you mentioned Trados Studio: for some file types (like XML, for example) it allows to add an embedded content processor that will take care of any embedded HTML tags. Check the [Trados Studio help](http://producthelp.sdl.com/SDL_Trados_Studio_2015/client_en/About_Embedded_Content_Processors.htm) for details. The output format of this process is not nice, but at least it will get the tags right.

You could also use the Okapi framework to convert your format to XLIFF and define a [pipeline](http://okapiframework.org/wiki/index.php?title=Rainbow_-_Edit_/_Execute_Pipeline) that does all the conversions you need. Okapi is very powerful, but not always intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree conversions should be avoided if possible, but they shouldn't "break characters" as you described as long as the proper encoding is used. The biggest issue I've seen so far is writing my own XLIFF serializer, especially with CAT tools adding "unexpected" tags in the translated string(they're valid XLIFF tags, but you have to parse them).
Thanks for mentioning Okapi, unfortunately I see .NET is not supported anymore.

Comment: The breaking characters situation happens when you have several nested formats (like HTML inside javascript inside csv) and you get asked to resolve entities and escaped characters so that the translators only see the literal characters that they have to translate. 

You mentioned .NET - are your strings inside resx files? Then Passolo or Catalyst would be the translation tools of choice, and you don't need to worry about XLIFF.

Out of curiosity: what kind of unexpected tags do CAT tools add? Can you ignore them or strip them out as long as the XLIFF is valid?

Comment: The content which needs to be translated is user content, it's created in a HTML5 WYSIWYG web app (with an ASP.NET backend) I'm working on. For example, imagine text widgets with rich text which need to be translated. I need to implement a feature to export the rich text of the widgets to something which can be translated by CAT tools and then implement an import feature. 
During testing on manual XLIFF files I saw Trados adds a `<mrk>` tag in XLIFF, see similar question, you can find others: https://community.sdl.com/solutions/language/translationproductivity/f/90/t/4950

Comment: note `mrk` is a valid XLIFF tag, it's just that it looked a bit unexpected when thining about implementing parsing the XLIFF, since the tag was added by CAT tool, it wasn't in my XLIFF.

Comment: That's strange indeed. Trados Studio inserts segmentation tags in its own SDLXLIFF files, but it should not save them back to the translated XLIFF if there were none in the original. You can safely ignore all `<mrk mtype="seg">` tags (assuming that you don't create any, of course). It may also insert additional tags to ensure that every segment is well-formed. It may also insert `<note>` elements when translators create comments, and it will definitely insert a `<target>` for every `<source>`. :-) I guess you have to do some parsing if you want to go the XLIFF way. Plain HTML might be easier.

Comment: I agree that with HTML it looks easier as no XLIFF serialization is needed. However, XLIFF is a dedicated XML format for translation tools, which has few nice features. For example, you can put in XLIFF notes/comments for translators. CAT tools render these comments.
I wish XLIFF had a simpler way to support HTML in the `<source>` without the need to encode from HTML to XLIFF inline tags (like `<g>`).  Apparently XLIFF doesn't support this.

Comment: Another thing I tried is the external files feature in XLIFF http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#external-file. I added a reference to an external HTML file, but neither Trados nor Memq render the HTML file or used it in any way.
About the `mrk` tag added by Trados: I think Trados is actually importing the XLIFF to its own SDLXLIFF format you mentioned. It's not using the XLIFF format to do the translation. So when you save to XLIFF it's actually converting/exporting from SDLXLIFF to XLIFF. That's why it appears like it adds `mrk` tags which were not in the original XLIFF

Comment: The external file feature in XLIFF refers only to the skeleton file, which is the original file from which translatable content is extracted. When translating monolingual files (Word docs, XML files, ...) it is useful to have the content of the original file at hand: either inside the XLIFF (the internal file) or as a reference (the external file). Without this the translators could not do previews. And you are right about how Trados Studio uses SDLXLIFF: it is the internal format for saving bilingual documents. In my opinion they should not pollute the input XLIFF with their tags.

Comment: I agree with @AndreiN. at that XLIFF must (and does) try to accommodate many translation-related use cases in real life, including HTML conversions. Many of our tools support XML, HTML, JSON etc. for translation purposes and this has, I believe, actually slowed down the progress of XLIFF. Look at the v2, it is SO MUCH better.